# Is the quote "there is no saint without a past and no sinner without a future" attributed to St. Augustine?

Tags: origin, augustine

This quote is often attributed to St. Augustine, but I have not been able to find anything that cites where in his works he writes this, nor have I found any historical account where he says this in a public setting such as a sermon. I would really appreciate if someone could find why this is attributed to Augustine, so that I know if it's falsely attributed to him or not.

> "there is no saint without a past and no sinner without a future"

P.S. I found the answer myself. This quote is not attributed to St. Augustine or Pope Francise as it is spread on internet. It is attributed to Oscar Wilde. Oscar Wilde's quote was used by many authors and among them as Persian author Mirza Ahmad Shorab whose work contain this quote. Oscar Wilde was born much before Mirza.

Comment: @NigelJ lol why would you copy my answer? and DV my questions? Is question out of context? Is it off-topic? Just because you didn't like my retort. You DV it lol! Funny peace loving religious people. Plagiarism is not welcomed.

Comment: A basic fact like this isn't really something that plagiarism would apply to. And all votes are anonymous, so please don't accuse people of downvoting your question.

Comment: Yes, it is attributed. But it is also attributed to others as well. There is no readily available documentation which reliably substantiates who first coined the saying.